# Controller response to Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In the products index page I'm listing all the products' names. I also have a form to create a new product. When I submit the form I'm able to create a new product but the list of products is not getting updated until I refresh the page.

I'm using this as a reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

**Product Index:**

```
<ul class="updated_products"><%= render 'products' %></ul>


<%= form_for(@product, remote: true) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>

<script>
$('#new_product').bind('ajax:success', function(){
  this.reset();
$(".updated_products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products') %>") ; 
});

</script>
```

**Products Partial:**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li><%= product.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

**Products Controller:**

```
  def index
    @products = Product.all
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    #@product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**create.js.erb:**

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products') %>").appendTo(".updated_products);
```

**Update:**

After adding format.js {} to the respond_to I can see in my log that is working:

Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  Rendered products/_products.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered products/create.js.erb (9.0ms)

But it's still not updating on the page.

I'm sure the problem is the content of my create.js.erb file:

```
$(".updated_products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products') %>") ;
```

**Fixed:**

In the view I changed the ul that renders the products partial from class of updated_product to id. Also changed it in the create.js.erb file

**View:**

```
<ul id="updated_products"><%= render 'products' %></ul>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#updated_products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products') %>") ;
```

Comment: Try to add `format.js {}` in respod_to block

Comment: I think it's working because I can see an ActionView Template Error in the log.

Comment: I've updated the post with the result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using js or json format request? Controller responds_to html and json. If json, successful create renders :show. If js (include format.js in controller), you do not need to bind ajax:success.

Comment: @Alexei.B  I'm using js, As soon as I added that line to the controller, it starter to work. Thanks